# Do "Beta Updates" of tvOS collect significantly more telemetry data than the stable release? What potential privacy issues can arise?

Tags: appletv, privacy, beta

Because you can easily install a beta release on tvOS and also revert back to the stable channel, I often do this.

Now a colleague told me that **I should never install beta releases** because they collect much more data for debugging purposes. Is that true? What privacy issues can arise with beta releases that don't exist with the stable release?

Comment: You can set up a network proxy and red the program details and Apple publishes a detailed privacy statement so you can always request a copy of all your data to inspect what is recorded and retained. How can we do better than Apple’s documentation here? This seems highly opinion based as no one can speak for Apple internally here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole point of taking part in a beta is to test out the software in your environment, and report to Apple any problems. That means providing them with enough data to fix it. Your personal details are not useful (generally) in fixing bugs.

More data is sent, yes. But it's mostly about the technical environment, code status, and so on.

If you don't want to 'help' (and risk problems arising from software that hasn't been thoroughly tested yet), then you shouldn't participate.